# JBoss AS7 Hornetq - RemoteConenctionFactory lookup fails with RoundRobinConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy NotSerializableException

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq, notserializableexception

I'm using JBoss AS 7 Hornetq. Our standalone java application interacts with a queue and sends messages. We had the entire environment setup and it was working pretty smoothly. Suddenly, one fine day, our standalone application failed with the below exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.hornetq.api.core.client.loadbalance.RoundRobinConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy
```

Detailed exception stack trace is below

> javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.hornetq.api.core.client.loadbalance.RoundRobinConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy]
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:104)
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:79)
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:79)
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:83)
>   at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>   at com.infosys.lbs.publishing.LocationProcessor.postMessageInQueue(LocationProcessor.java:377)
>   at com.infosys.lbs.publishing.LocationProcessor.process(LocationProcessor.java:69)
>   at com.infosys.lbs.publishing.main.Publisher.main(Publisher.java:34)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.hornetq.api.core.client.loadbalance.RoundRobinConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:891)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1063)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:885)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1063)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:998)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:885)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:62)
>   at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:119)
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$2.write(Protocol.java:138)
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.WriteUtil.write(WriteUtil.java:61)
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:128)
>   at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by: an exception which occurred:
>   in field loadBalancingPolicy
>   in field serverLocator
>   in object org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory@ea074d

Exception was happening when the app was trying to lookup the connection factory

```
QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory)context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

Below are the steps on how we resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

There was almost zero help for resolving this issue. A web search on this exception returned next to nothing. However, this particular thread on JBoss AS Dev site spinned a thought in my head: [RemoteConnectionFactory is not found when looking up in a remote client](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4217)

The scenario mentioned in this thread was not same as ours. (In our app this is the first and the only lookup happening.) This thread got me thinking towards a possible connection factory initialization issue. While there is nothing I could do to debug or find the issue around it, I thought that if I could reinitialize it, that would help.

So I tried lookup with `java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` As expected it failed with a NamingException. Hoping that this naming syntax (using java:/) would have resulted in a reinitialization, I tried lookup again with `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory`. And bingo!!! it worked!

Unfortunately, we still don't know why it happened, and if it is just a one-off case! Documenting it here just in case some mortal soul hits this issue.

Comment: The issue has reappeared and now doesn't get solved with the above trick (hence, I have unaccepted the answer). Any JBoss experts, pls?

Comment: Just came across this question after encountering a similar problem. For your specific error, it looks like there's a related bug which is claimed to be fixed in JBoss 7.1.3 https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4217
Perhaps that fixes the problem?